# Authentication credentials were not provided django-rest-auth

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I have an application which I implemented django restframework and django reat-auth and jango framework jwt. I followed the instructions and every thing works fine in the browser. I now decided to test out the connection in postman and trying to get the logged in user's details which the endpoint is `/rest-auth/user` but i get the following error

`{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}`

and I decided to copy the returned Token and put it in the header of the user url as

```
"Authorization": "Token ahagjbeghq7hbcvgqhvwqu08hevug.jwhhwiiwhw",
"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

after modifying the header with the returned token I expected it to display the user's details but instead I still got

```
{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

but I can verify that the token is correct through the url provided by the restframework jwt

`/api-token-verify` which retuns the token value back. this is my django rest authentication classes

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',

    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly',

    ),

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `JWT` instead of `Token` inside `Authorization` header for jwt token:

```
"Authorization: JWT <your_token>"
```

Comment: it requested that i input username

Comment: @King I mean you should do `"Authorization": "JWT ahagjbeghq7hbcvgqhvwqu08hevug.jwhhwiiwhw",`

Answer (score 0):

As @neverwalkaloner mentioned already `JWT` keyword suppose to be the value of Authorization in the header section of Postman. [Docs](https://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/)

Additionally, if you don't want JWT as a keyword in with your token, you can customize it from your settings:  with following key: `JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX`

```
JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_encode_handler',

    'JWT_DECODE_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_decode_handler',

    'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_payload_handler',

    'JWT_PAYLOAD_GET_USER_ID_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_get_user_id_from_payload_handler',

    'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_response_payload_handler',

    'JWT_SECRET_KEY': settings.SECRET_KEY,
    'JWT_GET_USER_SECRET_KEY': None,
    'JWT_PUBLIC_KEY': None,
    'JWT_PRIVATE_KEY': None,
    'JWT_ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'JWT_VERIFY': True,
    'JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION': True,
    'JWT_LEEWAY': 0,
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=1),
    'JWT_AUDIENCE': None,
    'JWT_ISSUER': None,

    'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': True,
    'JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=7),  
    'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'Bearer', #this most commonly accepted way
    'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': None,

}
```